# Should I set the `apollographql-client-version` to a default value or leave it empty if I don't have a version?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm using the Apollo GraphQL client to make requests to a GraphQL service, and I noticed that some examples include an `apollographql-client-version` header in the request. I don't have a specific version to set for this header, but I'm not sure if it's necessary to set a default value or if I can leave it empty.

I know it's not required, but it can be useful for analytics and troubleshooting purposes.

Should I set a default value for the `apollographql-client-version` header in my GraphQL requests, or is it okay to leave it empty? Are there any best practices or recommendations regarding this header?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to set the apollographql-client-version to a value such as "unknown" or "unversioned" instead of leaving it out. This is because Apollo Studio relies on this field to properly categorize and analyze client traffic.

If the field is left out entirely, the traffic will be categorized as "Unrecognized Traffic". This can make it difficult to identify and analyze client traffic in the Studio. By setting a value for this field, even if it is "unknown" or "unversioned", you provide more information to Apollo Studio and make it easier to analyze your client traffic.